# Is my question about configuring a AT&T fiber router for passthrough/bridge operation appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question yesterday, not 100% sure it is appropriate for the site:

[How to configure the AT&T (Arris) BGW-210 router for IP Passthrough using static IP(s) and pointing to Unify Dream Machine Pro?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1040169/how-to-configure-the-att-arris-bgw-210-router-for-ip-passthrough-using-static)

I tried to be as detailed as possible and there's nothing subjective about this question at all. It is about configuring routers for a business network.

Is this question appropriate or should I delete it and move it to a different Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's on-topic, but due to the equipment used and complexity I don't know if you will have a direct answer fast.

[Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the only other site that could maybe a good place to ask such question but I'm not familiar if it would be on-topic or not. I can ask a moderator from there if it's ontopic if you want. If yes I suggest to close your question here and repost as a migration keep the posted date, as such your question would not be listed in the latest questions feed. It kinda limit the visibility.